# The number of iterations of a for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, complexity-theory

I can't figure out for the following for-loop, how many time it will execute? It seems to me that it will never stop running as `i` will never be less than 0. But I know that `i` is an `int`, so I'm quite confused about when the loop will stop. Many thanks for your help!

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i/2) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Also is the complexity `log2(n)`?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: You mean iterations, not irritations :)

Comment: That's one irritated loop.

Comment: Here is a demo with `n = Integer.MAX_VALUE`: https://ideone.com/IfAjMn

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

For `n <= 0` it will be never inside.

For `n > 0` it will be executed `log2(n) + 1` times

---

```
n = 8
```

It will be invoked for `i = 8, 4, 2, 1` so finally, `3 + 1 = log2(8) + 1`

---

It also works with @Keppil test:

```
30 < log2(2147483648 - 1) < 31
```

and the result set has 31 elements.

Answer (score 0):

It will run for a number of iterations,given by **log2(n)**, the last one being when i=1. When the condition is checked the next time, i = 1/2 in int, which evaluates to zero and violates the condition and exits the loop. So it depends on the value of **n**.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code a little bit to see what happens there:

```
int n = 50;
for (int i=n; i>0; i=i/2){
    System.out.println("i: " + i);
}
System.out.println("1/2 in Java is: " + 1/2);
```

The output is:

```
i: 50
i: 25
i: 12
i: 6
i: 3
i: 1
1/2 in java is: 0
```

Now you should be able to understand why this loop ends.